# How to cancel the overlap of points, and spread out the points(like a small cluster) with the same coordinates?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a dataset, the format is [[idx, x-coord, y-coord]...]:

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 0, 1], [5, 0, 1], [6, 1, 1], [7, 1, 0], [8, 1, 1], [9, 1, 0], [10, 1, 0], [11, 1, 0], [12, 1, 0], [13, 1, 0], [14, 1, 0], [15, 1, 0], [16, 0, 1], [17, 0, 1], [18, 1, 0], [19, 0, 1]]
```

if I use `scatter` function to show them, like:

```
dataset_point = np.array(dataset_point)
plt.scatter(x = dataset_point[:,1],y = dataset_point[:,2])
plt.show()
```

[image]

It can only show three points in the map, however, I want to distinguish points in same coordinates, like a small cluster, so all points in same coordinates can be seen in the map. Is there some method in matplotlib can finish it?

Comment: I tried to add np.random.rand() in x and y, but I cannot ensure all points didn't overlap...

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such method in matplotlib, the closest is seaborn's [swarmplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) but this is for categorical data only (doesn't jitter for **both** x and y)

Comment: Can you comment on whether or not the given answer is helpful for your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some random values. E.g. `np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N)` would add some small Gaussian perturbation to each of `N` values.  `np.random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2, N)` would distribute the points into a small rectangular area. If you have many more points, you could set the region a bit larger, and also use `alpha` to make the scatter dots semi-transparent.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset_point = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 0, 1], [5, 0, 1], [6, 1, 1], [7, 1, 0],
                          [8, 1, 1], [9, 1, 0], [10, 1, 0], [11, 1, 0], [12, 1, 0], [13, 1, 0], [14, 1, 0], [15, 1, 0],
                          [16, 0, 1], [17, 0, 1], [18, 1, 0], [19, 0, 1]])
N = dataset_point.shape[0]
plt.scatter(x=dataset_point[:, 1] + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N),
            y=dataset_point[:, 2] + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N),
            alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: how do you ensure that there's no overlapping here?

Comment: Overlap is not ensured, but quite unlikely. `alpha` helps to cope with overlapping points, darkening areas with a lot of overlap.

Comment: yes, I see - but this is essentially what OP already tried as per his comment (except for the alpha)